# beamer, pstricks (texlive 2014)

Tags: beamer, pstricks

Since updating ubuntu to 14.10 (and 15.04 recently) i cannot succeed in compiling the following source:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}%
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
%\documentclass{beamer}%
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-node}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(-1, 0.0)(10, 8)
\cnode*(2.5,1){.5ex}{1}\rput(2.5,0.3){1}%
\cnode*(3,6){.5ex}{2}\rput(3,6.7){2}%
\cnode*(6,7){.5ex}{3}\rput(6,7.7){3}%
\cnode*(8,6.5){.5ex}{4}\rput(8,7.2){4}%
\ncarc[arcangle=0]{-}{1}{2}
\ncarc[arcangle=0]{-}{2}{3}
\ncarc[arcangle=0]{-}{2}{4}
\end{pspicture}
\caption{$G$}\label{fig:graph}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
%
\end{frame}
%
\end{document}
```

I use the following four commands:

1. `latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`
2. `dvips -o %-pics.ps %.dvi`
3. `ps2pdf %-pics.ps`
4. `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

where `%` is replaced by the filename. The code above allows me to replace the first two lines by the third in order to compile beamer-slides while the setting above produces lecture notes.

Lecture notes work fine, beamer presentation aborts with the following message:

> Process started
>
> Error: /typecheck in --div--
>
> Operand stack: 1 0 0.0 TeXcolorgray 65781.8 Execution stack:
>   %interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval--
>   2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false
>   1 %stopped_push 1967 1 3 %oparray_pop 1966 1 3 %oparray_pop 1950 1 3
>   %oparray_pop 1836 1 3 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- %errorexec_pop
>   .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2
>   %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval--
>   --nostringval-- 5 --nostringval-- %repeat_continue --nostringval-- Dictionary stack: --dict:1186/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:0/20(G)--
>   --dict:129/200(L)-- --dict:181/300(L)-- Current allocation mode is local Last OS error: No such file or directory Current file position
>   is 148977 GPL Ghostscript 9.15: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
>
> Process exited with error(s)

Both versions, slides and lecture notes, work fine on ubuntu 14.04 with texlive 2013 and ghostscript 9.10. On windows 8 with texlive 2014 and ghostscript 9.16 i encounter the same problem.

I assume the ps file is not ok (viewing it with gsview does not work either).

Anyone has an idea what goes wrong here?

Comment: I have no problem under MiKTeX loading `auto-pst-pdf` instead of `pst-pdf`, and loading it *after* `pst-node` either with `latex->dvios-ps2psf` or with  xelatex.